# File Pointer from CreateFileAsync in Windows 8 Javascript is undefined

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Writing a Windows 8 app in Javascript using Visual Studio Express. I'm not sure if I am missing a chaining dependency or something else, but I am giving my game users the ability to save their progress into a file (at least that's the idea). However when I run the following code it appears that even though I can see the file out there, the file pointer is turning out to be undefined. See anything I'm missing?

```
var myStats = new Array();
myStats[0] = myTitle;
myStats[1] = currPage;
myStats[2] = currStep;
myStats[3] = currTune;
myStats[4] = musicon;
myStats[5] = gameComplete;

var save01File = null;

            Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFileAsync("Asave01.dat", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).done(

                function (file) {
                    save01File = file;
                },
                function (error) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log(error, "sample", "error");
                });
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeLinesAsync(save01File, myStats).done(
                function () {
                },
            function (error) {
                WinJS.log && WinJS.log(error, "sample", "error");
                errCount++;
            });
            if (errCount == 0) {
                fileMenuTitle.text = "File Saved - Click Cancel";
                fileMenuTitle.text = fileMenuTitle.text + "\nto Return or Select Another File to Load";
                fileMenuTitle.color = "green";
            }
            else {
                fileMenuTitle.text = "There was an error saving that file.";
                fileMenuTitle.text = fileMenuTitle.text + "\nPlease Make Another Selection.";
                fileMenuTitle.color = "firebrick";
            }
```

Comment: `async` - that's the key here.   Do you understand what that means?  When an async operation happens, you can ONLY use the results of that operation inside the completion function.  You can't used it in the next function you call.

Comment: I thought there was a way to chain so that the following function can "wait" until the preceding function has completed? If not, then I am not clear how I would do the "write" of my array? Do the write function inside the "function (file)" of the initial create?

Comment: Yes, you do the write inside the success handler for creating the file or in a function you call from there.  That's the ONLY place you can do it.  Javascript does not have the ability to wait for anything.  This is asynchronous programming.  You do the work in the success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the promise pattern here:

```
var myStats = new Array();
myStats[0] = myTitle;
myStats[1] = currPage;
myStats[2] = currStep;
myStats[3] = currTune;
myStats[4] = musicon;
myStats[5] = gameComplete;

var save01File = null;

Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFileAsync("Asave01.dat", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (file) {
    save01File = file;
    return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeLinesAsync(file, myStats);
}).done(function() {
    fileMenuTitle.text = "File Saved - Click Cancel";
    fileMenuTitle.text = fileMenuTitle.text + "\nto Return or Select Another File to Load";
    fileMenuTitle.color = "green";
}, function (error) {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log(error, "sample", "error");
    fileMenuTitle.text = "There was an error saving that file.";
    fileMenuTitle.text = fileMenuTitle.text + "\nPlease Make Another Selection.";
    fileMenuTitle.color = "firebrick";
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Now if I can get the read working properly - am following the same pattern as you have above now, but suspect the line I think it has and the line I'm getting are not the same. Funny how so much of game programming is often the framework rather than the game :-)